# Is it possible to use a ftps server (NAS) to use as a virtual hard drive in VMware vSphere Hypervisor, if so, how?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, network-attached-storage, ftps

The title explains most of it. Basically, let's say I have a NAS(I don't). I want to allow another computer to use it as storage for a virtual machine on VMware vSphere Hypervisor. The software on the NAS will most likely be QTS by QNAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use the FTPS protocol as a data store for virtual disks.

VMware vSphere supports iSCSI, FCP, or NFS for data stores. Not FTP.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use a ftps server (NAS) to use as a virtual hard drive in VMware vSphere Hypervisor

No.

Edit - try reading the most basic of documentation, we expect that of SF question askers.

Comment: Then how can I use nfs?

Comment: Serverfault is a site for professional system administrators - the absolute minimum we expect of users is to have read some of the basic documentation and to have actually tried what they're asking about. I'm afraid this site isn't for you.